# Is there a way to work around the donet jit compile inliner time budget?

Tags: c#, .net, inline, jit

I have an application (a chess engine) written in C#. Because the strength of the engine is correlated with its speed it is important that the engine run as fast as possible.

To make the code more expressive and easy to read I used multiple shorts methods/properties to hide some complexity behind an explicit name. I marked most of theses method/properties with the an attributes to encourage inlining (`[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]`).

Now that I have enough functionality code to benchmark my engine and compared it to other written in C# it is much slower than what I expected (about 10x slower). I used the DOTNET_JitDisasm environment variable to see the assembly generated by the jit compiler for some of the more critical method and to my surprises and in some places most method/properties are not inlined. I understand that the `MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining` is just a suggestion, but some method that should be a single assembly instruction are not inlined.

During [my research](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/93069) I learned that the .net JIT compiler has something called the "inliner time budget" and that when this "buget" runs out, methods are no longer inlined even if they are marked with `MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining`.

Is there a way to increase this "budget" or in an other way make sure that method that would benefit from inlining are indeed inlined?

Comment: Nope, looks [hardcoded](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/a2ce8db5fb14df85cef03880a30133be198626e1/src/coreclr/jit/inline.h#L1063-L1069) atm

Comment: Also too much `MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining` can be counter-productive, because the method ends up too large. Only use this option when you feel this should be inlined and is not. And be aware that many features prevent inlining, not least `throw`, recursion and virtul methods.

Comment: If your code is 10x slower than some other program odds are *very* high it has nothing to do with inlining.  Outside of *very* unusual circumstances, it's not going to be anywhere *close* to a big enough impact to cause that kind of problem.  You should really start from square one and look at the program holistically to see what it's spending its time on, possibly comparing to these other programs (if you're able to do that).

Comment: @Servy, of course inlining is probably not the only reasons why my application is slower. But in this case I know it's a major part of the problem because I did a lot of tests. For example if I remove the AggressiveInlining on some method. Other method that were not inlined are now inlined (verified by checking the assembly generated) and the application becomes twice as fast, which is still 5X slower than expected. Also I think I'm in the "unusual circumstances" territory because I choose (maybe unwisely) to put lots of code in very small inlinable function for code clarity purposes.